# What is another name for Dick?

Tags: names, nicknames, offensive-language

Coming from ["Changes in English names of people"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8767/changes-in-english-names-of-people)  telling:

> Richard → Dick

Can I substitute Dick by Richard?
I need it to know because my Emails with the use of name Dick are being returned by Email filtering as obscene

Or what is substitute for name Dick?

I already asked it before but my question was deleted

Update:
Why is [Dick Cheney](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dick_Cheney), former Vice President of the USA, is always written/addresses everywhere in a tone of familiarity?
How can I call/address him without a tone of familiarity by a synonymous name?

So, I should address Dick Cheney as Richard Cheney instead?
Have I understood correctly the answers?

Comment: If someone goes by the name of "Dick", there is, of course, no guaranteed substitute for the first name that the person actually uses.  Your email filter is laughably aggressive.

Comment: In modern culture, nicknames are chosen strictly by the bearer: if someone introduces himself as Dick, call him Dick, not Richard or Rich or any other version of the name.

Comment: Classical names tend to have many variants. For Richard: Rich, Richy, Ritchie, Richie, Rick, Ricky, Dick and probably more.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you looking for other nicknames for Richard because an (over-zealous) obscenity filter choked on Dick? If so, some possibilities include Rich, Richie, Rick, or Ricky. If you want, you could even try resurrecting some now-obsolete nicknames: Hitch, Hick, Dickon, Ricket, Hicket, or Hudde. (I got these from *The Oxford Dictionary of English Christian Names* by E.G. Withycombe, under Richard.)

Answer (score 2):

Richard is the safest one. The others assume a tone of familiarity that may be unwelcome (or are just outright bizarre.)

Comment: Why is [Dick Cheney](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dick_Cheney), former Vice President of the USA, is always written/addresses everywhere in a tone of familiarity?  How can I call/address him without a tone of familiarity by a synonymous name

Comment: @vgv8 you do not address the former Vice President by his first name. You address him as "Mr. Cheney".

Comment: As long as your email filter accepts it, *Dick* is fine, since he's already referred to himself as such. In a pinch, *Richard* or *Mr. Cheney* are the safest substitutes.