# What is the meaning of "Dick" when it is a person's name?

Tags: meaning, names

Some people are named "Dick". What does "Dick" mean when it is a name?

Comment: One of Richard Nixon's political nicknames was "Tricky Dick."

Comment: ...but "Little Richard" chose to never abbreviate his name. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Richard

Comment: @Urbycoz - Can you blame him?

Comment: Related: _[What is another name for Dick?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/15284/5822)_ and _[People's names as names for genitalia?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/24308/5822)_

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Dick* is a nickname for Richard. When it’s not a name, *dick* is slang for a penis or an unkind person. There are a lot of jokes about this.

From [Behind the Name](http://www.behindthename.com/name/richard):

> Means “brave power”, derived from the Germanic elements *ric* “power, rule” and *hard* “brave, hardy”. The Normans introduced this name to Britain, and it has been very common there since that time. It was borne by three kings of England including Richard I the Lionheart, leader of the Third Crusade in the 12th century. Famous bearers include two German opera composers, Richard Wagner (1813–1883) and Richard Strauss (1864–1949), as well as British explorer Sir Richard Burton (1821–1890) and American musician Little Richard (1920–).

In the Middle Ages, it was common to use rhyming nicknames of this sort, many of which live on:

- Richard → Rick → Dick
- Edward → Ed → Ned
- Robert → Rob → Bob
- William → Will → Bill

See [Name Nerds](http://www.namenerds.com/uucn/advice/nickhistory.html) for a list of these and other nickname patterns.

Comment: Meaning of the name Richard: http://www.thinkbabynames.com/meaning/1/Richard

Comment: So you are saying Dick isn't a real name?

Comment: very interesting.

Comment: Anything can be a real name if you want it to be. But Jon is right- "Dick" is derived from the English name "Richard".

Comment: @EmreVeriyaz: It's a real name, but most commonly used as a nickname: the majority of people called *Dick* are actually named *Richard* legally.

Comment: When thinking of the fact that "dick" is slang for "penis" or "unkind person", it is very strange to me that people named Richard actually choose to use the nickname "Dick"!

Comment: @awe: Rich and Rick are other common alternatives. A lot of Richards really hate being called Dick.

Comment: @Jon: I know a Richard from Ireland that actually signs his official company emails with Dick...

Comment: Wait, are we sure Dick rhymes with Richard, because it really does not appear to, to me.

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski: They don’t rhyme. Dick is a “rhyming nickname” for Richard. Rhyming names are described in the Name Nerds link in the answer. I also added more detail (“Richard → Rick → Dick”) to clarify.

Comment: _Dick_ was a very common nickname for _Richard_ for centuries. It has become much less commonly used since the 20th century as the slang meaning has become more widely known, but _some_ Richards still choose  to use it and ignore the slang.

Answer (score 6):

Back in the days, people used to shorten their names, Rick for Richard and use a nick name that rhymes with the shortened name, in this case, Dick. Other examples are: Edward-Ed-Ted. Robert-Rob-Bob....